# Deleting a PARTICULAR word from a file using shell script

Tags: shell

Hi I am having a problem in deleting a particular set of words from a file using Shell script. Here goes my problem,
My file: group.dat
Sample lines
**ADMIN

ADMINISTRATION

ADMINISTRATOR**
My Script: groupdel.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
groupf="<pathtofile>/group.dat"
tmp="<pathtofile>/te"
delgrp()
{
        echo "Enter the group to be deleted"
        read gname
        echo "-------------------"
        for gn in `cat $groupf`
        do
                if [ "$gname" = "$gn" ]
                then
                        sed -e "s/$gname//g" $groupf > $tmp&&mv $tmp $groupf
                        echo "deleted group"
                        cat $groupf
                        exit 1
                fi
        done
}
echo "Welcome to Group delete wizard"
delgrp
```

Output: 
Enter the group to be deleted

### **ADMIN**

deleted group

ISTRATION
ISTRATOR

Problem: My problem is I dont want the script to delete ADMINISTRATION or ADMINISTRATOR but to delete only ADMIN, any help how to achieve it.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is one group *per* line, and the group name is the only thing on the line, use anchors in your regular expression:

```
s/^$gname:.*//g
```

If you have Perl installed, you can probably simplify this a bit with something like this:

```
if grep -q "^${gname}:" $groupf ; then
    perl -ni -e "print unless /^${gname}:/" $groupf
    echo "Group deleted."
else
    echo "No such group $gname."
fi
```

Or even

```
grep -v "^${gname}:" $groupf > $tmp && \
    cp -f $tmp $groupf && rm -f $tmp
```

which will copy all lines *except* the matching one to the temporary file, and then copy the tempfile over the original file, replacing it.

Note that I suggest using a `cp` rather than a `mv` in order to retain the permissions of the original file; `mv` will result in the edited file having permissions set according to your umask with no concern for the original permissions.

So, for the complete script:

```
#!/bin/sh
groupf="<pathtofile>/group.dat"
tmp="<pathtofile>/te"
delgrp()
{
    echo -n "Enter the group to be deleted: "
    read gname
    echo "-------------------"
    if grep -q "^${gname}:" $groupf ; then
        grep -v "^${gname}:" $groupf > $tmp
        cp -f $tmp $groupf
        rm -f $tmp
    else
        echo "No such group '$gname'"
    fi
}
echo "Welcome to Group delete wizard"
delgrp
```

That should work reliably.

Comment: @RoUS, Along with group name i do have associated users in the file.

Comment: @Srikanth Do any of the users have the same names as groups?  When removing group names from the file, do you want to remove the associated users from it as well?  If so, we need to know the syntax of the user lines..

Comment: @RoUS, thanks for the quick reply. Users may have the same names as groups, pls find below the syntax of the file **group.dat**  `ADMIN:admin,srikanth  DEVELOPER:dev1,dev2  ADMINISTRATOR:GL_ADMIN`

Comment: @RoUS thanks for your valuable help. It solved my problem. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @ROUS, I am having one more problem, its not deleting the first line if file has only one line. Pls help

Comment: @Srikanth Which method are you using?  The `grep` or the `perl` ?

Comment: @Srikanth The `grep` method should be reliable; I've updated my answer with a complete update to the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
groupf="<pathtofile>/group.dat"
tmp="<pathtofile>/te"
delgrp()
{
    echo "Enter the group to be deleted"
    read gname
    echo "-------------------"
    sed -e "/^$gname[[:blank:]]/d" "$groupf" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$groupf"
    echo "deleted group $gname"
    cat "$groupf"
    return 0
}
echo "Welcome to Group delete wizard"
delgrp
```

Assuming that the group name is at the beginning of the line and there are other things on the line and you want to delete the whole line, use the regular expression and command as shown.

There's no need for a loop since `sed` will iterate over the lines of the file for free.

You should `return` from a function rather than `exit` from it. Zero means success. One indicates an error or failure.

Always quote variable names that contain filenames.

Comment: I had added the exact syntax as you suggested, but it is not deleting the any line from the file and showing the same group list in the file.

Comment: @Srikanth: You didn't show that you had colons separating the group name from the rest of the line. Use this `sed` command: `sed -e "/^$gname:/d"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and pls accept my apologies for missing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\W` to denote the start and end of a word, if they are separated properly:

```
sed -e "s/\(\W\)$gname\(\W\)/\1\2/g" $groupf > $tmp&&mv $tmp $groupf
```

Comment: I had changed the syntax, but the script doesn't delete anything. It shows all the contents as it is without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a readable alternative to sed:

```
awk -v to_delete="$gname" -F: '$1 == to_delete {next} {print}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use sed ?

```
sed 's/^word$//g'
```

Also you can use regex to specify multiple words

```
sed 's/word1|word2//g'
```

I didn't try this, but this is what you need. Just take a look on Internet on the sed syntax.

Regards